# instance Monoid Monad

Tags: haskell, monads

`Monad` is a monoid, however it's a monoid in a different way than, say, `Integer`. I wonder if there is a way to write `Monoid'` and `Monad'` such that both `Integer` and `Monad'` can be expressed as instances of the same `Monoid'` typeclass?

Comment: I think you want to read [this blog post](http://www.jonmsterling.com/posts/2012-01-12-unifying-monoids-and-monads-with-polymorphic-kinds.html) explaining how to use kind polymorphism to unify the two under the same type class.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez: Can you turn that into an answer? It actually answers the question as I understand it, unlike the current answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm turning my comment into an answer at Tikhon's request.  [This blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20160408195501/http://www.jonmsterling.com/posts/2012-01-12-unifying-monoids-and-monads-with-polymorphic-kinds.html) shows how to unify `Monad` and `Monoid` under the same type class using kind polymorphism.  This is slightly different from Tel's answer in that the monad is implemented as a monoid in the category of endofunctors, rather than a monoid in a Kleisli category.

Comment: I've changed the link to point to the Wayback Machine, but it would be better if you summarized Jon's blog post in the answer here so that it will survive.

Answer (score 6):

So, let's pick a particular way `Integer` has a `Monoid`

```
instance Monoid Int where
  zero = 0
  plus = (+)
```

and now here's a `Monad` `Monoid`

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
instance Monad m => Monoid (Kleisli m a a) where
  zero = id
  plus = (.)
```

and here's another

```
instance MonadPlus m => Monoid (m a) where
  zero = mzero
  plus = mplus
```

I'm not sure how to express the "Monad is a monoid in the category of endofunctors" formulation in Haskell offhand, however.